# How to Clean-up my SWC project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, swc

I created a Flex Library project in Flash Builder 4.7 and the added a simple Action Script Class to it. Build fine.

When I use a "decompiler" with the resulting swc file, I see an "unwanted" class, with a weird name, intentionally "unique" I presume, derived from `flash.display.Sprite`.

I also decompiled some other swc files (not mine) and didn't found such "extra" class in them, just the code meant to be here.

How to create an empty SWC project in Flash Builder, without the product auto-generating a sprite class, or how to clean it up?

Newbie in `flex` here, feel free to edit / downvote / close (with some explanations)

Comment: Why does the "unwanted" class matter?  That's normal behavior in a Flex project; part of the compilation process is generating Actionscript classes from MXML files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal behavior for a Flex type project.  If you want to avoid the autogenerated Flex class, create an "ActionScript Library Project" instead.